# Can Epicor Prelude be integrated with a java based web application?

Tags: epicorerp, epicor

One of our US-based customer in the business of distribution of HVAC products wants to use Epicor Prelude product. 
We want to know whether Prelude can be integrated with a java based web application and if it supports -Web services, Messaging queues and Enterprise Service Bus / Middleware(eg. BizTalk).

Answer (score 0):

Well it is entirely too late but it does support web services and you can write a Java front end web page and access most of Prelude's functions.

I'm surprised they asked on Stack Overflow since we have an excellent customer service department willing to answer these questions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).